# Prevent SLURM from running in /home folder

Tags: linux, slurm, sbatch

Is there a way for SLURM to prevent users from executing tasks via sbatch or srun that involve writing to the /home/username folder? Can SLURM actually monitor this? If not, what could be a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could make a job submit script to prevent submitting jobs with a working directory under $HOME, and while that would be a decent hint to users to not do that it wouldn't fundamentally prevent a job from opening files under $HOME.

I guess you could make the home quota small, if you want to prevent running I/O intensive jobs there.